# Trying to set --std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x via CGAL_CXX_FLAGS ignores values

Tags: c++, cmake, cgal

I am trying to compile some code that will use CGAL but uses an include file that produces an error. The error says to compile with with either `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x`.

If I add either `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x` to `CGAL_CXX_FLAGS` i,e 
`cmake -DCGAL_CXX_FLAGS='-std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x -I` etc it just ignores what I have set for `CGAL_CXX_FLAGS`.

If I omit `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x` from the `CGAL_CXX_FLAGS` it sets the C++ complier flags okay but fails on the compile of the include file.

Comment: Try `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-std=c++0x'`

Comment: Thanks already tried that with no change

Comment: I don't think CMake handles single quotes in command line args.  Have you tried `cmake . -DCGAL_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++0x"`?

Comment: Try to use add_Definitions("-std=c++0x") in the file CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: I'd usually just `export CXX='g++ -std=gnu++11'`. What header is it that asks to use these flags?

Comment: Typed it in wrong to this forum, I do have double quotes cmake -DCGAL_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++0x" so that did not fix it

Comment: The header is a FreeCAD one ...../Base/TimeInfo.h:41: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
cmake -DCGAL_CXX_FLAGS='-std=c++0x
```

is not correct. CMake accepts that form of -D option without any warning, but the behavior is not what you want. Check the documentation of CMake. The correct form is the following:

```
cmake -DCGAL_CXX_FLAGS:STRING='-std=c++0x'
```